# Variable selection based on PLS

Tags: feature-selection, regression-coefficients, partial-least-squares

What is the logical way to select the variables from PLS?

Does choosing the feature from loadings and loading weights make sense?

Loadings...

Loading weights...

Regression coefficients...

Variable importance on PLS projections (VIP)

Comment: That's not the point of PLS, variable selection, so your question does not make sense.

Comment: There is no logical way to select variables from PLS.

Comment: why? the information we get from PLS regression can be descriptive. there are dozens of papers in the literature, related to spectral datasets. see one review: [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169743912001542?via%3Dihub)

Comment: so we can select some features related to those info, and then we can decide which one is more dominant explaining the variances. however, my question is there are loadings, loading weights, regression coefficients, and VIP... so which one/s would be more appropriate?

Comment: Ok, before we answer, can you please amend your question to explain the following:  Why do you want to select variables, and what do you believe selection will result in (alternatively, what benefit do you think selecting variables will provide you).

Comment: i aim to increase model accuracy with a few selected variables. so, i will use the information (loadings/loading weights/regression coefficients/vip score) from PLS, then with logistic regression the model will be tested.